# How can I report a problem when I can't get Blender (2.79b) to even open?

Tags: error

I recently installed Appleseed and the Blenderseed add-on to Blender 2.79b on my Macbook Pro.
The first time I tried to use the new renderer Blender froze and since then will not even open.
I've tried re-installing, re-downloading and installing a new copy and copying a working version of 2.79b from my Mac Pro to my laptop. None of this made any difference. 2.78 has the same issue but 2.76 and 2.80 will both run.
Any ideas for how to fix this?

Comment: Your title says you can't open blender, but the body of the question says that it froze. Can you clarify if Blender will open but freezes when you try to render or whether it won't even open. Also, previous to installing Appleseed, have you been able to use blender without these issues?

Comment: Blender was working fine before I tried Appleseed. Now all I see is the icon bouncing in the dock for a while, then nothing. Command-Option-Escape shows 'Blender (not responding)'

Comment: Did you erase user preferences and any files left after uninstalling 2.78-2.79? (usually in user's folder)

Comment: Can't find any preferences for appleseed or blender in user's folder or anywhere else for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to erase folder in /Users/Username/Library/Application Support/Blender in your mac